# Flower Symbol Meaning?

Tags: rascal-does-not-dream-of-bunny-girl

[image]

From Seishun Buta Yarou wa Yumemiru Shoujo no Yume wo Minai, what is the meaning of this flower symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is known as a "hanamaru" it's been like a "very good" or a gold star award on exams or projects. Usually done to award younger kids.